# Passing ajax to php(laravel) and load the page that receives

Tags: laravel-4

Is it possible to pass a ajax value from a different page to a php(laravel controller) and {return View::make('page')->with('variable', $variable);} or load/view a different page with the variables in it??

Comment: why you dont open that page in new tab by providing button and click event.if you want to pass data then create inline form and submit that form and open in new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Create a link like `action('HomeController@getIndex', $params);` where $params is an array where multiple parameters will be sent by GET, what means the url will be look like `domain.com\param1?getParam1?getParam2`
In controller get those data by `Input::all();`. Hope that helps!